# mod_rewrite gives 404 when url contains words dvd-player - reserved words?

Tags: mod-rewrite, reserved-words

I am rewitting url-s (mapping subdomains to subdirectories) and it works perfect except for urls that contain the following words: "mp3-player" or "dvd-player". In this case I always get 404 error. It doesn't matter if the words are contained in a subdomain or in a path, if they are at the beginning, middle or the end:

http://blahblah-dvd-player-blahblah.example.com/blahblah/somefile.html

http://blahblah.example.com/blahblah-mp3-player-blahblah/somefile.html

All other subdomains and paths work perfectly. Urls that are not rewritten and contain those words also go well.

Could those be some kind of reserved words? Can somebody please help me? I have no idea how to debug this.

Problem is solved! It was caused by xss filter. 
Thanks everybody.

Comment: I managed to fix this in the meantime. The problem was caused by xss filter and not the url rewriting.